# Javascript getting params from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

not sure if this should be done in javascript or something else.  Basically, I have a little quiz type thing where all questions are on a single page.  I have an ajax function which checks what question it is, and if it is the last question, it will redirect the user to a new page e.g.

```
if(totalScore <= 10) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "php/handleData.php",
        data: { answers: ansArray, page: window.location.href, pt: "aa" }
    }).done(function( response ) {
        window.location.replace("page2.html" + '?le=' + le + '&ch=' + ch);
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus  ) {
        console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        window.location.replace("page2.html" + '?le=' + le + '&ch=' + ch);
    });
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the redirect also includes some additional parameters.  Therefore, when I am redirected, I am on a page like

> page2.html?le=1&ch=2

Now I dont necessarily need these params in this url, but it is the only way I could think about getting them over to page2.  Page 2 has a button on it like

```
 <a href="www.link1.com>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Visit link1.com ></a>
```

It is in this href where I need the params le and ch to be injected.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: See https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#search-set

Comment: Well you can set `le` and `ch` in `localStorage` and when you are on page2.html than can access from there.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery on `Page2.html` you can do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var le_val = getParameterByName("le");
    var ch_val = getParameterByName("ch");

    $("a.btn.btn-primary").attr("href","www.link1.com?le="+le_val+"&ch="+ch_val);
});
```